# How to calculate numerical age of an Object in Java

Tags: java, object, jvm, java-native-interface

I want to know age of an object in Java, when we use new keyword the user-defined object is created in Java, but when would it be destroyed ?

Is it the time taken to cross the perm space of the JVM? Can I know the numerical age of an object using JNI programming?

What is the relationship between survival space, perm space and object age?

Comment: You can't 'calculate' it. You would have to *record* it, in the object, or in a map keyed on the object.

Answer (score 2):

An object will be destroyed after it becomes eligible for GC and JVM decides to run GC in the heap area (new / old generation) where the object is located. You can know the moment when the is being destroyed by overriding finalize method or by using WeakReference and ReferenceQueue.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, an object's age is stored in [Object Header](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/a00b51b2dda4/src/share/vm/oops/markOop.hpp).

```
// The markOop describes the header of an object.
//
// Note that the mark is not a real oop but just a word.
// It is placed in the oop hierarchy for historical reasons.
//
// Bit-format of an object header (most significant first, big endian layout below):
//
//  32 bits:
//  --------
//             hash:25 ------------>| age:4    biased_lock:1 lock:2 (normal object)
//
//  64 bits:
//  --------
//  unused:25 hash:31 -->| unused:1   age:4    biased_lock:1 lock:2 (normal object)
```

So, may be you can get an object's age if you know the object's address.

> What is the relationship between survival space, perm space and object age?

Please read [Memory Management in the Java HotSpot Virtual Machine](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf).

[image]
<sub>(source: [oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/G1GettingStarted/images/slide1.png))</sub>

If an object's age exceed the age threshold, it will be moved from eden/survior to old generation.

Answer (score 1):

You can start the timer in constructor of the Object and stop it when finalize() is called. You can override finalize() of Object class. Just call super.finalize() before your timer logic in finalize() method.(GC thread will call finalize() on the Object instance to free it's resources)

Object are created in young gen which on survival from half GC go to old gen area. Perm gen is used to store Class information and not instances if it.

Comment: thanks ankit, can i expect the same output every time.we can't force GC to run. GC-cleanup activity will be performed on a bunch of objects. and running GC depends on JVM.

Comment: No you cannot. You cannot control when GC happens.