# Java - Getting the existing time of an object

Tags: java, oop

Let's say I created an object, like this

```
Object obj = new Object();
```

Now I want to get how long has the object existed, like

```
System.out.println("Creating object");
Object obj = new Object();
//Print 0
System.out.println("The object has existed for (ms): " + getTime(obj));
Thread.sleep(1000);
//Print 1000
System.out.println("The object has existed for (ms): " + getTime(obj));
```

How can I do so? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Similar Question: [How to calculate numerical age of an Object in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20943476/642706)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code. finalize() method run in destroy time of object.if the the object goes to garbage collector that finalize method run. in my code System.gc() use for call garbase collector. This code is very long. its only for understanding purpose. You can customize this code.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Thamira
 */
public class Demostra {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

        System.out.println("Creating object :" + sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
        Object obj = new Object() {

            @Override
            protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                System.out.println("The object has removed for : " + sdf.format(cal.getTime()));

                super.finalize(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

        };

        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

        System.out.println("The object has existed for : " + sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Demostra.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

        System.out.println("The object has existed for  : " + sdf.format(cal.getTime()));

        obj = null;

        System.gc();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Demostra.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This might be useful for my other uses, but sadly it can only show the time when being destroyed.

Comment: did you run my code? it gives starting time and destroy time. Then you can write algorithm for existed time. Can you explain more about your problem.

Comment: My problem is that I am trying to find a way to get the existing time of an object, which is not overrided, whenever I want, instead of only being able to get the time only when the finalize() is called.

Comment: It is not general purpose of object. In java no implementation for that. Read documentation of Object.class after you can write  customised  object for that and extend it to your object. I can write it and send you latter.

Comment: FYI, the old [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) classes are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system). Supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Comment: Thank you. @basil_bourque I try to explain his perpose only. we can change that to java.time

Answer (score 3):

There's no *automatic* way to do this, no `getTime(obj)` method present. The only way to do this is to write code yourself to manually retrieve the system time, often done via `System.currentTimeMillis()` when and where needed, and then subtracting the values thus obtained to get a duration or time-difference.

Now you can create a class that you yourself wire to have this functionality, that obtains its own creation time and stores it in a field, and than has its own methods that return duration of existence, and in fact this would be easy to do, and its implementation will be left as an exercise for the student.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
Duration.between( objectBorn , Instant.now() )
```

## java.time

The [answer by lakmal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41776446/642706) looks to be correct except that it uses the troublesome old date-time classes now legacy, supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

As the other Answer explains, Java objects do not track their time in existence by default. You must add your own code to track their birth and age.

### `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();  // Current moment in UTC.
```

In Java 8, the [current moment is captured](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now--) with a precision of milliseconds (or coarser granularity, depending on your computer hardware clock). In Java 9 and later, a [fresh implementation](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730) of [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) increases the potential precision to nanoseconds, depending on the capability of your computer hardware clock. To be clear, in both Java 8 *and* Java 9 you can represent a moment with up to nanoseconds resolution; only *capturing the current moment* is limited in Java 8.

### `Duration`

The [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class represents a span of time.

Here is a complete example.

```
package javatimestuff;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 *
 * @author Basil Bourque
 */
public class Life {

    private Instant objectBorn = null;

    // Constructor
    public Life () {
        this.objectBorn = Instant.now ();  // Capture the moment at birth of this object.
    }

    public Duration objectAgeAsDuration () {
        Duration d = Duration.between ( objectBorn , Instant.now () );
        return d;
    }

    public long objectAgeAsNanos () {
        Duration d = this.objectAgeAsDuration ();
        return d.toNanos ();
    }

}
```

Exercise that class.

```
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println ( "Please wait a few seconds as we birth a new `Life` object. " );

        Life l = new Life ();
        try {
            Thread.sleep ( TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis ( 3 ) );
        } catch ( InterruptedException ex ) {
            // Interruption may be this thread being woken.
            // …
        }

        System.out.println ( "The Life object’s age as Duration: " + l.objectAgeAsDuration () );
        System.out.println ( "The Life object’s age as nanoseconds: " + l.objectAgeAsNanos () );
    }
```

> Please wait a few seconds as we birth a new `Life` object.
>
> The Life object’s age as Duration: PT3.002S
>
> The Life object’s age as nanoseconds: 3010000000

## `finalize` is irrelevant and not dependable

Your comments talk about wanting to get the time when an object’s `finalize` method runs. You should know two important things in that regard:

- `finalize` happens *after* an object becomes a candidate for garbage collection, **any time after**. It may happen quickly or it may be quite a while later. The scheduling is up to the implementation of Java, not specified by the [Java spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/).
- `finalize` **may not run at all**. For example, a JVM may exit while choosing to immediately clear all objects including the garbage-collection candidates without executing the `finalize` methods at all.

Generally speaking, the `finalize` method is of little practical use. Common practice is define and call your own method (`teardown`, `shutdown`, whatever name you want) to immediately release any resources when finished using an object.

The `Object::finalize()` method has been officially deprecated in Java 9 and later as [documented here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize--) and [discussed here](https://hackernoon.com/java-lang-object-finalize-is-finally-deprecated-f99df40fa71). To quote the doc:

> **Deprecated.** The finalization mechanism is inherently problematic. Finalization can lead to performance issues, deadlocks, and hangs. Errors in finalizers can lead to resource leaks; there is no way to cancel finalization if it is no longer necessary; and no ordering is specified among calls to finalize methods of different objects. Furthermore, there are no guarantees regarding the timing of finalization. The finalize method might be called on a finalizable object only after an indefinite delay, if at all. Classes whose instances hold non-heap resources should provide a method to enable explicit release of those resources, and they should also implement AutoCloseable if appropriate. The Cleaner and PhantomReference provide more flexible and efficient ways to release resources when an object becomes unreachable.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).